# Hide CSS Element loaded from other CSS stylesheet

Tags: css, youtube

I'm trying to hide the YouTube Channel icon and title text that the YouTube embedded player displays on my webpage.

I attached an image of what I'm trying to hide here:
[YouTube Channel Icon and Title Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzYgO.png)

I've tried adding the following to my CSS style sheet to override the CSS that is loaded with the embedded player, but it's not working:

```
div.ytp-title-channel ytp-title-show-collapsed {display: none;}
a.ytp-title-channel-logo {display: none;}
div.ytp-title-expanded-overlay {display: none;}
div.ytp-title-expanded-heading {display: none;}
div.ytp-title-expanded-title {display: none;}
div.ytp-title-expanded-subtitle {display: none;}
div.ytp-title {display: none;}
a.ytp-title-link yt-uix-sessionlink {display: none;}
div.ytp-title-text {display: none;}
```

The youtube embedded player loads a CSS file named www-player.css. Is it possible to edit this CSS file after it's loaded?

I'm able to hide everything needed when using Chrome inspect developer tools, but how do I transfer what I want to do, to my actual web page?

Thank you.

Comment: You might just have to make your styles more specific, so that they override the specificity of the YouTube styles. You'll be able to tell in the inspector, as the less specific styles will be greyed out.

Comment: `I attached an image of what I'm trying to hide to this post.`  ... ? where ?

Comment: I edited the post with the image. Stackoverflow didn't let me embed since it's my first post.

@ralph.m How does the webpage know which CSS to use. Is CSS loaded in the header override all other CSS loaded elsewhere in a page?

Comment: The C in CSS stands for "cascade": each CSS rule had a weight or score, known as specificity, and the higher wins out, no matter where it is in the order. For example, an ID carries more weight than a class. Best to do a bit of reading on how to calculate specificity. You might need to add a few things to your rules, like a few ancestor elements — especially any with an ID. Or you could try `!important`, thought it's a bit dirty.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easier ways to do this is by using the CSS [`!important` rule](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp). This will override all previous stylings (unless there are more specific rules that also override the property with `!important`) for whatever you are selecting:

```
.ytp-title {
  display: none !important;
}
```